# Synchronize reads and writes using ADO.NET and the Access Database Engine

Tags: ms-access, ado.net, odbc, delay, jet

I'm using ADO.NET to communicate with a Microsoft Access Database (using the ODBC driver).

Because of the asynchronous write/read behaviour of Jet, sometimes, if you use different connections, (for instance one for writing and another for reading), a small delay between writes on one connection being read on a second connection could happen.

As explained here => https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200300

Unfortunately, the solution proposed is only valid for ADO (not ADO.NET).

Using transactions seems to reduce the issue but not to solve it.

Any ideas to solve this problem in ADO.NET?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for ODBC is right at the end of the Microsoft Support document you cited:

> Use the following method to synchronize writes and reads between 2 connections with the Microsoft Access ODBC driver ...
>
> 1. The writer must make the database updates (with or without a transaction) and then close it's connection.
> 2. The reader must close and re-open it's connection prior to attempting to read the data.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that connection pooling could interfere with the proposed solution for ODBC. The fix would be to not use connection pooling. (It's disabled by default for Access ODBC anyway, and it doesn't offer the same benefits for a shared-file database that it does for a client-server database.)

Comment: That would be a possibility, but would be great to find a way to do it without disabling connection pooling.